# Where to put the GPG keys in $HOME/.gnupg?

Tags: linux, gnu, gnupg, opensuse-11.4

I run OpenSuse 11.4 and KDE 4.6. I installed Thunderbird and Enigma.

Thunderbird is the following version: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; de; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 SUSE/3.1.7 Thunderbird/3.1.7

I have no clue where to put the GPG key. Some said that I have to put the GPG keys in `$HOME/.gnupg`. But, where should i find this directory? I looked through all the directories – I am lost!

When I have several keys, can I put all of them there? Does the system find the right ones on its own?

Comment: If that directory does not exist, you could create it.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I think that *Key To* isn't the path to the keys...

Comment: many many thanks for the quick reply. GREAT To hear from you. Well you want to have a screenshot of waht!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to import existing keys in your keyring. Enter the following command in the terminal:

```
gpg --import <path-to-keyfile>
```